# What to select next, for building Desktop-application?

Tags: frameworks, ide, groovy, desktop-application, griffon

I have been reading Groovy, and I'm half way down. I started to love groovy a lot, and apply it to solve some simple real world problem; As I love building web applications, i would go for reading Grails webframework as I know Groovy.

But If I want to build desktop-applications, which framework will be the good choice? I wanted to create a simple IDE for Groovy language(or say for any language), that can do syntax highlighting and other kind of stuffs.As mentioned earlier, I love Groovy a lot when compared to Java; And Griffon is a framework that is built on Groovy, mainly for creating Desktop-appplications. But I didn't find enough resources for Griffon!

Is Griffon is the good framework for those people who know and love Groovy(as I do)? Can I choose it for building a simple IDE as mentioned above? Or there are any other framework that is built on Groovy, which is good when compare to Griffon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem I have found with Griffon is that a number of the plugins are a bit out of date in that they aren't using the latest UI libraries (e.g. Flamingo, Substance, and SwingXBuilder, altho I think this has just been upgraded to use SwingX 1.6).

I am using SwingBuilder directly, with a few extensions I have added via my own builder implementation:

http://code.google.com/p/ousia

If you want to build an IDE I can recommend the RSyntaxTextArea component, as it has great support for many programming languages and is pretty simple to use:

http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/

Comment: thanks for sharing the **RSyntaxTextArea** component in the answer!

Comment: SwingBuilder is built into Groovy itself and makes building Swing UIs much simpler: 

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Swing+Builder

SwingXBuilder is a Griffon plugin and provides support for extra components from the SwingX library:

http://griffon.codehaus.org/SwingXBuilder

Answer (score 2):

Griffon is a fairly good MVC based framework, and is built on top of Java Swing. So it can do anything that Swing can do.

To be honest I found Griffon a little too much for relatively simple UIs, so I usually write my apps in Groovy using SwingBuilder directly.

If you really want to get into Griffon I recommend getting the Book 
[Griffon in Action](http://www.manning.com/almiray/) It seems to be the only place where everything is documented, although the web page is coming along and improving all the time.

Comment: nice, but there are anyother frameworks like griffon built on groovy?

Comment: Not that I know of, however take a look at SwingBuilder and things like MigLayout and GlazedLists, with these tools using Groovy and Swingbuilder directly is much easier IMHO than using a framework.

Answer (score 2):

There are definitely various resources out there that will let you learn more about Griffon, for example the Griffon Guide -> http://dist.codehaus.org/griffon/guide/index.html

"[Griffon in Action](http://www.manning.com/almiray/)" is another popular resource which you can buy in electronic form today; being the author of both makes me a little biased ;-)

You can keep up to date on Griffon news by following the mailing lists and [@theaviary](http://twitter.com/theaviary) on Twitter

Comment: Thank you author ;) and with the help of Griffon can i build IDE? Is that possible?